# Using regular expressions in firestore security rules (testing for spaces in string)

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am reading through documentation and found that firestore security rules expose `.matches()` helper for regex related operations.

Does something similar exist to test agains regular expresion, i.e. I need to check if `request.resource.data.username` does not have spaces in it.

In javascript land it would go something like

```
!/\s/.test(request.resource.data.username)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern that match any character but a whitespace is `\S`. To match any 0 or more occurrences, apply `*` after it, or if you want to match 1 or more occurrences use `+` quantifier. To match the start of string use `^` (only works as start of string when used at the start of the Firebase pattern), to match the end of string use `$` (only works as end of string anchor when at the end of the pattern).

So, use

```
.matches(/^\\S+$/)
```

or

```
.matches(/^\\S*$/)
```